# How do mark up my css so that this element takes to height its supposed to

Tags: html, css, flexbox

https://codepen.io/Champion36O/pen/MoyyMv
What do I have to do in order to get **.body element to stretch and take up the all available space in the wrapper**? Basically, I want to see footer at the bottom of the container. I thought to add the **flex-grow** property would do the trick but nope..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Learning Flexbox </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexbox.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1> CSS Flexbox Practical Examples </h1>

    <div class="example">
      <h2>3 Column layout</h2>
      <div class="example-page example-layout">
        <header>Header</header>

        <div class="body">
          <div class="col1"> Main Content </div>
          <div class="col2"> Navigation </div>
          <div class="col3"> Sidebar </div>
        </div>

        <footer> Footer </footer>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .example-page {
      min-height: 45px;
      padding: 2em;
    }
    .example {
      border: 2.5px solid black;

    }

    h2 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1em;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }

    .example-layout {
      display: flex
      flex-direction: column;
      height: 300px;
    }

    header, footer {
      padding: 20px;
      background: #666;
      color: white;
    }

    .body {
      display: flex;
      flex-grow: 1;
    }
```

Comment: You have a tiny syntax error. Your code is correct. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Missing Semicolon**

```
.example-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Haha yeah I just noticed. Thank you.

Comment: Happens to all of us. Depending on what text editor or IDE you're using, I would suggest using a CSS linter for syntax checking! Would increase your workflow!!

Comment: I didn't even know that existed! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read this good guide about the flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I corrected your code below. `flex` should be applied to the container.
I also added a `box-sizing: border-box` to all the elements, that will really help with sizing them. Other than that you should avoid using .body as a class name, as it's already an HTML tag, that can lead you to mistakes in the future.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.example-page {
  min-height: 45px;
  padding: 2em;
}
.example {
  border: 2.5px solid black;

}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.example-layout {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
}

header, footer {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks! Noted about the .body mark up i'll stay away from using that. Appreciate the resource as well; great resource!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers so far. I really appreciate it! However, I found the solution to my problem. I was simply missing the semi-colon after display:flex in .example layout. NOOB error. Thanks again. I'll be more observant next time.